# Using implicit flow to get Cookies

Tags: cookies, identityserver3

Using IDServer3, OWIN, angular2, WebAPI, etc.

I have 2 clients setup within IDSrv, one MVC and one JS/Angular and I'm trying to achieve SSO. Currently SSO works if I login through the MVC app (hybrid flow) since this will set the cookies in the browser and will be picked up when I navigate to login via implicit flow. However if I first attempt to login via the JS app (implicit flow) no cookie is set, and therefore no SSO is achieved. How can I configure IDSrv to set the cookies when we login via implicit flow as well as hybrid flow?

EDIT:
In other words, is it possible to use bearer token auth for WebAPI and cookie auth for MVC together and still acheive SSO between the two.

EDIT 2: 
Since an answer confirmed my understanding, I will rephrase the question once more. Using implicit flow in a JS (angular 2) client, how can I get a token and a cookie when authenticating via the auth end point in IDSrv? Currently just a token is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - because the authentication session is not maintained between idsrv and your apps - but between idsrv and your browser.

Each app must then set its own session - MVC does that via a cookie. In JS typically using something like session storage.

To go through your scenario:

1. Open MVC app

   - authenticate with idsrv. idsrv sets an authentication cookie
   - redirect back to mvc
   - MVC sets its own cookie to sign in the user
2. Open JS app

   - authenticate with idsrv. This time there is already an existing logon session. no login UI is shown and tokens are sent back to JS directly
   - JS validates response and remembers users in local storage

Every client application needs its own way to sign in the user (cookie vs session storage). Single sign on happens because there is an additional session with idsrv (maintained by idsrv own cookies).

Comment: Could you explain how session storage would solve the problem of SSO when first login via implicit client? How would IDSrv pick this up when we hit the MVC client?

Comment: Or maybe I have a misunderstanding... When I login via the MVC client, is the cookie I see containing the ID_Token generated by the MVC app owin middleware or by IDSrv? EDIT: on second thought it must be generated by IDSrv since it is signed...

Comment: I added more info. If that is still unclear, you need to read up on some fundamentals.